# JMenu appears behind JTree when JTree has focus?

Tags: java, swing

The JMenu works correctly when I click my mouse over it.

[image: before]

I click my mouse away and it disappears (normal).
I then double click the only entry in my JTree.

Then when I click my JMenu it looks like this. It appears behind the JTree???
[image: after]

When I resize the window it returns to normal. Until the JTree has focus again.

This is what my code looks like, I'm subclassing a jframe and this code is in the constructor

```
Container cp = getContentPane();

//1. menu
JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();
//...

cp.add(menu, BorderLayout.NORTH);

//2. split pane
JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT);
//...
{
    //3a. scrollpane (left)
    ScrollPane treeView = new ScrollPane();
    treeView.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    sp.add(treeView, JSplitPane.LEFT);
    {
        //3ai. treeview
        tree = new ObjectTree();
        treeView.add(tree);
    }

    //3b. scrollpane (right)
    ScrollPane tabView = new ScrollPane();
    tabView.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(0,0));
    sp.add(tabView, JSplitPane.RIGHT);
    {
       //3bi tabview
       ObjectTabPane view = new ObjectTabPane();
       tabView.add(view);
    }
}

cp.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
this.setSize(700, 500);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the menu be actually closed when it loses focus?

Comment: It closes when it loses focus. But when I click the only entry on the Jtree, then click the menu again. The menu now has focus but is behind the tree

Comment: the JMenuBar shouldn't be on the contentpane

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're mixing Swing and AWT components. Don't do this, because it leads to the problem you're facing. Use a `JScrollpane` rather than a `ScrollPane`.

Comment: +1 hmmm but looks like as swing.JFrame v.s. awt.Frame too, since from Java1.6_012 allowed http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/ and http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/mixing_components/

Comment: haha oh wow, I can't believe I didnt type the J in front of scroll pane.